# unable to set cell data in excel

Tags: java, apache-poi

i have created the below function to set cell data in excel but when i am setting data. the file is getting corupted and me getting errror as **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openxmlformats/schemas/spreadsheetml/x2006/main/CTDxfs$1**
[My Jars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUCZk.png)

```
 public boolean setCellData(String sheetName,String colName,int rowNum, String data){
    try{
    fis = new FileInputStream(path); 
    workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

    if(rowNum<=0)
        return false;

    int index = workbook.getSheetIndex(sheetName);
    int colNum=-1;
    if(index==-1)
        return false;


    sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(index);


    row=sheet.getRow(0);
    for(int i=0;i<row.getLastCellNum();i++){
        //System.out.println(row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue().trim());
        if(row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue().trim().equals(colName))
            colNum=i;
    }
    if(colNum==-1)
        return false;

    sheet.autoSizeColumn(colNum); 
    row = sheet.getRow(rowNum-1);
    if (row == null)
        row = sheet.createRow(rowNum-1);

    cell = row.getCell(colNum); 
    if (cell == null)
        cell = row.createCell(colNum);


    cell.setCellValue(data);

    fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path);

    workbook.write(fileOut);

    fileOut.close();    

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: post the whole class

Comment: Pleas show the full stack trace of the error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [read the Apache POI FAQ!](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025). Specifically, from the [Apache POI FAQ entry on "I'm using the poi-ooxml-schemas jar, but my code is failing with "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openxmlformats/schemas/*something*"](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025):

> To use the new OOXML file formats, POI requires a jar containing the file format XSDs, as compiled by XMLBeans. These XSDs, once compiled into Java classes, live in the org.openxmlformats.schemas namespace.
>
> There are two jar files available, as described in the components overview section. The full jar of all of the schemas is ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar, and it is currently around 15mb. The smaller poi-ooxml-schemas jar is only about 4mb. This latter jar file only contains the typically used parts though.
>
> Many users choose to use the smaller poi-ooxml-schemas jar to save space. However, the poi-ooxml-schemas jar only contains the XSDs and classes that are typically used, as identified by the unit tests. Every so often, you may try to use part of the file format which isn't included in the minimal poi-ooxml-schemas jar. In this case, you should switch to the full ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar. Longer term, you may also wish to submit a new unit test which uses the extra parts of the XSDs, so that a future poi-ooxml-schemas jar will include them.

So, short term, you just need to switch from the `poi-ooxml-schemas` jar to the larger (and complete) `ooxml-schemas` jar `ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar`. Longer term, you need to submit a junit test to the Apache POI project which uses your desired CT class, and that class will then be automatically included in the smaller `poi-ooxml-schemas` jar in a future release.